# Как очистить treeView?

Tags: c#, winforms

В treeView создаётся дерево глубиной 2-3 уровня.

Как очистить treeView, чтобы treeView после создания дерева снова вернулось к первоначальному состоянию - стало пустым?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так: `treeView1.Nodes.Clear();`